# How to apt-get remove without autoremove on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

I want to remove from my system ONLY 2 packages:

```
apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop memtest86+
```

but program wants to autoremove other 371 packages which I don't want to remove neither mark them as "no longer required". How do I prevent apt from autoremove those other packages? How do I tell the system to "enable" previously marked packages as "no longer required"?

Answer (score 0):

`ubuntu-desktop` is a very small tiny package; it contains only two files, `/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-desktop/changelog.gz` and `/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-desktop/copyright`. What is has are *dependencies*; it *depends* on a whole lot of packages, which together constitute the Ubuntu desktop. If you remove `ubuntu-desktop`, those many packages will become "no longer required", which is to say, as far as the package manager is concerned, they will no longer have a reason to be present. Which they actually won't: they are there in order to satisfy the dependencies of `ubuntu-desktop`.

To mark one or more packages as manually installed you can use `apt-mark`. To answer your specific question, you can always take the list of packages which `apt-get` tells you that after removing `ubuntu-desktop` will become no longer required, and feed it to `apt-mark` to mark them as manually installed.

Answer (score 0):

From apt-mark manual:

> When you request that a package is installed, and as a result other
>   packages are installed to satisfy its dependencies, the dependencies
>   are marked as being automatically installed, while the package you
>   installed explicitly is marked as manually installed. Once an
>   automatically installed package is no longer depended on by any
>   manually installed package it is considered no longer needed and e.g.
>   apt-get or aptitude will at least suggest removing them.
>
> **Manual is used to mark a package as being manually installed, which
>   will prevent the package from being automatically removed if no
>   other packages depend on it.**

```
apt-mark manual <packages>
```

Where `<packages>` is the package (or package list separated by whitespaces) you don't want to remove automatically.

```
apt-mark manual unity8-desktop-session ubuntu-software
```

Comment: While that command is definitely relevant to the question, could you please explain *how exactly* it is relevant and how OP can use it to solve the issue underlying their question?